# How to get Window.UI.Color from Windows.UI.Colors?

Tags: c#, colors

I have a combobox to select the background color of a given application object. I'm filling the combobox with the code below, but I don't know how to retrieve the selected value to change the background color of the other object. Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxBackgroundColor" SelectionChanged="cbxBackgroundColor_SelectionChanged" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="32" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Code Behind

```
public VideoPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    cbxBackgroundColor.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
}

private void cbxBackgroundColor_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Code to set MyObject.Background with cbxBackgroundColor.SelectedItem 
}
```

Comment: You set a `PropertyInfo[]` as source, so the value can be returned by `var color = (Color)(cbxBackgroundColor.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo).GetValue(null);`. Or `var color = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((cbxBackgroundColor.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo).Name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works in wpf.

```
private void cbxBackgroundColor_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Color selectedColor = (Color)(cbxBackgroundColor.SelectedItem as PropertyInfo).GetValue(null, null);
   this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(selectedColor);
   or
   MyObject.Background = new SolidColorBrush(selectedColor);
}
```